# Permission handling for privileged system apps

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-rom

I'm writing an Android app, that will run on custom hardware with a ROM that I have control of.

The device will run a single application (as a launcher) and once the device is deployed I (generally) do not have access to it anymore. The app also has support for updating itself.

As such, I need a way to properly handle permissions for the app i.e. permissions need to be granted automatically (including dangerous ones) if they are ever added to the manifest.

Now, the app is being signed by the same certificate as the Android OS running on the device, and the app is placed in the priv-app directory when the device is flashed.
I assumed that this would automatically grant permissions but this does not appear to be the case.

I have tried adding `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` to the manifest, and that does indeed grant all permissions, but since there are already quite a few legacy devices "in the wild", adding this option makes it so that the app can no longer be updated (throwing a `INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE` error).

So, what is the best way to handle permissions in this case? Is there some other voodoo magic I am missing here? Should I just bite the bullet, add the `sharedUserId` option and manually update all devices (undesired, but possible option)?